# Python issue with global?

Tags: python

I'm try to make a password guesser using python for a project. However, I've gotten stuck. Heres the code I'm using currently.

```
dictfile = open('c:/PC/wordsEn.txt', 'r')
DictionaryWords = dictfile.readlines()


Password = 'zygote10'

Intadd = 0

def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        global Intadd
        print(x .replace("\n", str(Intadd)))
        if x .replace("\n", str(Intadd)) == Password:
            print("Congrats, you found the password!")
            break
        else:
            while Intadd < 10:
                Intadd += 1
                print(x.replace("\n", " ") + str(Intadd))


def Password_Tester():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        if x .replace("\n", "") == Password:
            print('Found it!', x, 'is the password!')
            break
    else:
        Number_Finder()


Password_Tester()
```

When I run the code, I want to see something like this:

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
apple5
apple6
apple7
apple8
apple9
apple10
ate1
ate2
```

and so on. (Basically I want the code to run a word, changing the number everytime until the number in it reaches 10, then change the word and then repeat the process).

However, when I run the code, I see this:

```
apple1
apple2
apple3
apple4
apple5
apple6
apple7
apple8
apple9
apple10
ate10
aviation10
```

(After apple, the words don't repeat the process of going from 1 to 10, and the word just changes with the number 10 after it)

I think the problem lies in the global command. I'm fairly new to Python, so I'm sorry if theres an obvious solution. Thanks guys!

Comment: So where are you setting `Intadd` back to 0 again? Did you expect it to go back to 0 on its own when the function ends? That's not how globals work.

Comment: What are the contents of `wordsEn.txt`? It might be helpful to write a simplified version of this code that operates on a small handful of strings contained in a global variable list.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `global` in general, so a local variable and a for-loop:

```
def Number_Finder():
    for x in DictionaryWords:
        for n in range(10):
            x2 = x.strip()+str(n)
            print(x2)
            if x2 == Password:
                print("Congrats, you found the password!")
                return
```